# Regression intercept with sum of weights equal to one

Tags: r, lm

I'm studying how Microsoft (MSFT) is explained by other tech stocks, namely Google (GOOG), Facebook (FB) and Amazon (AMZN).

```
getSymbols(c("MSFT","GOOG","FB","AMZN"), from=as.Date("2015-01-01"))
```

Then I run a simple linear regression and extract the coefficients

```
reg <- lm(log(Ad(MSFT)) ~ log(Ad(GOOG))+log(Ad(FB))+log(Ad(AMZN)))

w <- reg$coef[2:4]

sum(w) = 0.9021839
```

Now I want the sum of the weights to be 1, i.e

```
sum(w) = 1
```

so I do the following:

```
w_adj <- reg$coef[2:4]/sum(reg$coef[2:4])
```

This way the sum of the weights is equal to one, but obviously the intercept must have changed.

How do I estimate the new intercept, i.e. the intercept of w_adj ?

I though the following:

```
dat <- merge(log(Ad(GOOG)),log(Ad(FB)),log(Ad(AMZN)),all=FALSE)

adj <- xts(dat %*% w_adj, index(dat))

reg_adj <- lm(log(Ad(MSFT))-adj ~ 1)
```

Does it make sense ?

I also thought about weighted regression as another option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are completely rewiring the model by scaling the coefficients down _after_ they're fitted.  You need to constrain them to sum to one during the least squares fitting.  These are two totally different things.